# System.LoadLibrary(libname) crashing on Nvidia Tegra 2 chipset (Android Samsung Tab) in Javacv code

Tags: android, opencv, javacv, galaxy-tab, tegra

I have made a custom camera in Andorid using [Javacv code](https://code.google.com/p/javacv/).
I hadn't included all the .so files but only those which seems required for my application.
As in the screen shot below:

[image]

It works well on Samsumg Galaxy S2, S3 and Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc.
No problem at all. But when I tried to run it on Samsung P7500 Galaxy Tab 10.1, it crashed on the very first line of Javacv code I have used which happens to be:

```
yuvIplImage = IplImage.create(previewWidth, previewHeight,  IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

Logcat Ouput for this attempt:

```
07-08 13:30:13.930: I/ActivityManager(192): START {intent.toShortString} from pid 7836
07-08 13:30:14.000: I/ActivityManager(192): Start proc app.processName for activity hostingNameStr: pid=7847 uid=10001 gids={1006, 3003, 1015, 1023}
07-08 13:30:14.190: D/NvOsDebugPrintf(116): GetParameter(): 37 not supported
07-08 13:30:14.190: E/NvOmxCameraSettingsParser(116): Param type 71 not supported
07-08 13:30:14.240: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18783: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
07-08 13:30:14.250: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
07-08 13:30:14.250: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18783: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
07-08 13:30:14.250: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x000f
07-08 13:30:14.250: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 5673
07-08 13:30:14.250: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0007
07-08 13:30:14.250: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18783: Ljava/awt/image/BufferedImage;.getSampleModel ()Ljava/awt/image/SampleModel;
07-08 13:30:14.250: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x74 at 0x0011
07-08 13:30:14.250: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve instance field 5673
07-08 13:30:14.250: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x007f
07-08 13:30:14.260: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve static method 18764: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0033
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x00b7
07-08 13:30:14.260: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve static method 18764: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00c6
07-08 13:30:14.260: W/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: unable to resolve static method 18764: Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;.getInstance (I)Ljava/awt/color/ColorSpace;
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x00de
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0077
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4957 at 0x2d in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.cloneBufferedImage
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4957 at 0x18 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
07-08 13:30:14.260: D/dalvikvm(7847): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4958 at 0x7d in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
07-08 13:30:14.270: D/dalvikvm(7847): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4965 at 0x167 in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
07-08 13:30:14.270: D/dalvikvm(7847): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x4966 at 0x17f in Lcom/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_core$IplImage;.getBufferedImage
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:4.0.4/IMM76D/XWLP5:user/release-keys'
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925): pid: 7847, tid: 7847  >>> com.javacv.recorder <<<
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925):  r0 5be58ce7  r1 00000008  r2 5be58ce8  r3 000270b4
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925):  r4 5be7fc00  r5 00000008  r6 00000004  r7 000040f1
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925):  ip 00000000  sp beb570e0  lr b0003a43  pc 5be58cec  cpsr 00000010
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925):  d2  46fffe0000000000  d3  46fffe00c7000000
07-08 13:30:14.820: I/DEBUG(1925):  d6  4252000000000000  d7  3eaaaaab3f800000
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be58ccc e1a00006 eb004a45 eb004b9b 0002745c  ....EJ...K..\t..
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be58cec f2c00010 e79f3003 f443078f e12fff1e  .....0....C.../.
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be58cfc 000270b4 e59f300c e79f3003 e2833008  .p...0...0...0..
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be58d0c e5803000 e12fff1e 000270a4 e12fff1e  .0..../..p..../.
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a40 3d014790 dcf62d00 bf00bd70 4c05b510  .G.=.-..p......L
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a50 447c2001 f00160e0 2300ffb1 f00160e3  . |D.`.....#.`..
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be46000-5be7d000 /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): 5be7d000-5be7e000 
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a0  b00094f0  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a4  b0009f60  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a8  00000413  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570ac  5be52a70  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b0  b0009934  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b4  5be46114  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b8  b001c88c  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570bc  b00094fc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c0  b000ebf0  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c4  00000000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c8  b001b868  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570cc  5be81000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d0  0003f000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d4  b00040d9  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d8  df0027ad  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570dc  00000000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925): #00 beb570e0  b000ebf0  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570e4  5be7fccc  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570e8  00000031  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570ec  b0004627  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f0  00000000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f4  00000000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f8  0003f0f1  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570fc  b0003be7  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57100  b0006cbc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57104  b0006bcc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57108  00000000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb5710c  b000ebf0  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57110  b001b97c  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57114  00000031  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57118  000040f1  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb5711c  b001b868  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57120  5be81000  
07-08 13:30:14.930: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57124  0003f000  
07-08 13:30:16.230: I/DEBUG(1925): !@dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 7847
07-08 13:30:23.850: D/Zygote(114): Process 7847 terminated by signal (4)
07-08 13:30:23.850: I/ActivityManager(192): Process app.processName (pid 7847) (adj 0) has died.
```

My Super Hero "Mr. PID 7847" Died :(

From this log I can easily interpret app is trying to link to libtbb.so
But no clue what went wrong.

I attached source code to javacv jar but still no clue.
Then I removed the jars and included code in my project with required jars, As you can see in screen shot below:

[image]

Using break points I found that app is crashing at

```
com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary() method's line 
              System.loadLibrary(libname);
```

And in logcat output I got almost similar code but now I know which part of the code is not working.

```
07-08 15:39:43.920: D/dalvikvm(8900): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so 0x41362fd0
07-08 15:39:43.920: A/libc(8900): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x57c48cec (code=1)
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925): Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:4.0.4/IMM76D/XWLP5:user/release-keys'
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925): pid: 8900, tid: 8900  >>> com.javacv.recorder <<<
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925): signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 57c48cec
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  r0 57c48ce7  r1 00000008  r2 57c48ce8  r3 000270b4
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  r4 57c6fc00  r5 00000008  r6 00000004  r7 000040f1
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  r8 b001b868  r9 57c71000  10 0003f000  fp 57c36000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  ip 00000000  sp beb570e0  lr b0003a43  pc 57c48cec  cpsr 00000010
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d0  400000003eaaaaab  d1  3ff0000042c80000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d2  46fffe0000000000  d3  46fffe00c7000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d4  0000000046fffe00  d5  0000000000000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d6  4252000000000000  d7  3eaaaaab3f800000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
07-08 15:39:44.420: I/DEBUG(1925):  scr 80000010
07-08 15:39:44.460: E/DataRouter(110): usb connection is true 
07-08 15:39:44.460: E/DataRouter(110): DSR is ON. Don't send DTR ON.
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):          #00  pc 00012cec  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):          #01  lr b0003a43  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): code around pc:
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c48ccc e1a00006 eb004a45 eb004b9b 0002745c  ....EJ...K..\t..
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c48cdc fffffe00 fffffea8 fffffeb0 e59f300c  .............0..
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c48cec f2c00010 e79f3003 f443078f e12fff1e  .....0....C.../.
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c48cfc 000270b4 e59f300c e79f3003 e2833008  .p...0...0...0..
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c48d0c e5803000 e12fff1e 000270a4 e12fff1e  .0..../..p..../.
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): code around lr:
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a20 2301b90a 1e4be004 0483eb00 33fff04f  ...#..K.....O..3
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a30 460d009e 6822e006 1e5019a4 d8001cc3  ...F.."h..P.....
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a40 3d014790 dcf62d00 bf00bd70 4c05b510  .G.=.-..p......L
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a50 447c2001 f00160e0 2300ffb1 f00160e3  . |D.`.....#.`..
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): b0003a60 bd10ffad 00005aa6 4b1ab51f 22004601  .....Z.....K.F."
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): memory map around addr 57c48cec:
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c23000-57c36000 
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c36000-57c6d000 /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): 57c6d000-57c6e000 
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): stack:
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a0  b00094f0  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a4  b0009f60  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570a8  00000413  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570ac  57c42a70  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b0  b0009934  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b4  57c36114  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570b8  b001c88c  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570bc  b00094fc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c0  b000ebf0  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c4  00000000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570c8  b001b868  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570cc  57c71000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d0  0003f000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d4  b00040d9  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570d8  df0027ad  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570dc  00000000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925): #00 beb570e0  b000ebf0  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570e4  57c6fccc  /data/data/com.javacv.recorder/lib/libtbb.so
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570e8  00000031  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570ec  b0004627  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f0  00000000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f4  00000000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570f8  0003f0f1  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb570fc  b0003be7  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57100  b0006cbc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57104  b0006bcc  /system/bin/linker
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57108  00000000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb5710c  b000ebf0  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57110  b001b97c  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57114  00000031  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57118  000040f1  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb5711c  b001b868  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57120  57c71000  
07-08 15:39:44.540: I/DEBUG(1925):     beb57124  0003f000  
07-08 15:39:45.980: I/DEBUG(1925): !@dumpstate -k -t -n -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_native -m 8900
07-08 15:39:45.980: I/BootReceiver(192): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-08 15:39:45.990: I/dumpstate(8938): begin
07-08 15:39:54.060: I/ActivityManager(192): Process app.processName (pid 8900) (adj 0) has died.
07-08 15:39:54.070: D/Zygote(114): Process 8900 terminated by signal (4)
07-08 15:39:54.070: W/ActivityManager(192): Force removing r: app died, no saved state
```

Further investigation in "Mr. PID 7847" murder case has lead me to the facts that it is not the code that is at fault but in my Galaxy Tab chipset is NVIDIA TEGRA 2 and this is reason my app is not working.

The main line in crash log looks like :

```
 signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 57c48cec
```

Intro about [SIGILL is here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGILL#SIGILL) and a [Related Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26199#c2) and a [Related Article](http://docs.nvidia.com/tegra/data/How_to_Use_OpenCV_for_Tegra.html).

So far it seems like its a matter between armeabi-v7a and armeabi.
Now I have a MCQ :
Please let me know which of the following is correct question by me and explain its answer too.

1) If I have missed or neglected something until now while using Javacv ?

2) Or if Javacv is not Tegra 2 compatible at all and no hope is there ?

3) Or  should .SO filesbe compiled with some additional settings (armeabi-v7a and armeabi) which will make it Tegra 2 compatible  , in such case how can I do that ?

4) What Should I do to run it on Tegra 2 chipset devices like Galaxy P7500 10.1 Android Tab ?

My Device's build.prop file:

```
# begin build properties
# autogenerated by buildinfo.sh
ro.build.id=IMM76D
ro.build.display.id=IMM76D.XWLP5
ro.build.version.incremental=XWLP5
ro.build.version.sdk=15
ro.build.version.codename=REL
ro.build.version.release=4.0.4
ro.build.date=Fri Aug  3 20:31:10 KST 2012
ro.build.date.utc=1343993470
ro.build.type=user
ro.build.user=dpi
ro.build.host=DELL162
ro.build.tags=release-keys
ro.product.model=GT-P7500
ro.product.name=GT-P7500
ro.product.device=GT-P7500
ro.product.brand=samsung
ro.product.board=GT-P7500
ro.product.cpu.abi=armeabi-v7a
ro.product.cpu.abi2=armeabi
ro.product.manufacturer=samsung
ro.product.locale.language=en
ro.product.locale.region=GB
ro.wifi.channels=
ro.board.platform=tegra
# ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device
ro.build.product=GT-P7500
ro.tether.denied=false
# Do not try to parse ro.build.description or .fingerprint
ro.build.description=GT-P7500-user 4.0.4 IMM76D XWLP5 release-keys
ro.build.fingerprint=samsung/GT-P7500/GT-P7500:4.0.4/IMM76D/XWLP5:user/release-keys
ro.build.characteristics=tablet,nosdcard
# Samsung Specific Properties
ro.build.PDA=P7500XWLP5
ro.build.hidden_ver=P7500XWLP5
ro.build.changelist=997989
# end build properties
ro.opengles.version = 131072
wifi.interface=wlan0
ro.ethernet.interface=eth0
ro.ethernet.autoEnable=yes
rild.libpath=/system/lib/libsec-ril.so
rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyS0

persist.sys.storage_preload=1

# Multimedia prop for Smart View
media.enable-commonsource=true

#
# ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES
#
dev.sfbootcomplete=0
drm.service.enable=true
dalvik.vm.heapstartsize=5m
dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=64m
dalvik.vm.heapsize=256m
ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-samsung
ro.error.receiver.default=com.samsung.receiver.error
ro.url.legal=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/phone-legal.html
ro.url.legal.android_privacy=http://www.google.com/intl/%s/mobile/android/basic/privacy.html
ro.com.google.locationfeatures=1
ro.kernel.qemu=0
drm.service.enabled=true
ro.setupwizard.mode=OPTIONAL
ro.com.google.apphider=off
ro.com.google.gmsversion=4.0_r3
dalvik.vm.dexopt-flags=m=y
net.bt.name=Android
dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt
```

Comment: which armeabi used in that device in which you are getting this error ?

Comment: give me the result of this `Log.i("CPU ABI is :",android.os.Build.CPU_ABI);`

Comment: android.os.Build.CPU_ABI  = armeabi-v7a

Comment: so your device uses `armeabi-v7a` CPU architecture,you need to build libraries for this architecture using NDK.

Comment: Yes I have that idea but as I have only jars and .SO files of Javacv project by Samuel, I don't know how can I build libraries for that architecture ? Any help , can you please see Javacv project https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Comment: You'll need to recompile the .so files and figure out what set of options work. I'm not sure myself why it doesn't work, because Tegra 2 is ARMv7, so it should work.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, Can you please let me know from where I can get whole NDK project which also include Android.mk file. I mean Can you please just give me a start how can I re-compile , right now I have no idea.

Comment: The Galaxy Tab 10.1 does not have NEON support. So when you recompile your files, you will need to make sure you remove the NEON flag. I believe the compiled files provided by Samuel were compiled with the NEON flag.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I am already on the way to compile tbb.so myself from the source code available at http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/download. If this one get loaded I will look for other .SO re-compilation if required.

Comment: @SourabSharma Me to facing same issue. Can you please help me how to resolve this. its working in moto g and not working samsung duos please help me

Comment: @MuraliGanesan: Please see the answer below. Its just an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of this problem, I have found an alternative way.

Simply check is custom camera is supported on device in which user is using your app.

So that you can handle it and start native camera instead.

```
private void checkIsCustomCameraSupported()
    {
        int isNeon = com.javacv.recorder.Util.checkNeonFeature();
        if (isNeon == 0)
        {
            IS_CUSTOM_CAMERA_ENABLED = false;
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Custom Camera is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //  finish(); or intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        }
    }
```

For further details:

https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord/tree/master/TouchToRecordDemo